# Updating a column with data from another table

Tags: sql

I have been trying to update some rows of a column in a database using the following statement but its not working

```
UPDATE member_payment AS p 
SET    debtor_receipt = (SELECT Sum(d.amount) 
                         FROM   debtor_receipt d, 
                                customer c, 
                                dairy_member m, 
                                member_payment p, 
                                vendor v 
                         WHERE  m.member_id = c.member 
                                AND d.customer = c.customer_id 
                                AND p.payee = v.vendor_id 
                                AND v.member = m.member_id 
                                AND d.txn_date = '2013-04-30') 
WHERE  p.payee IN(SELECT vendor_id 
                  FROM   vendor v, 
                         debtor_receipt d, 
                         customer c, 
                         dairy_member m, 
                         member_payment p 
                  WHERE  v.member = m.member_id 
                         AND m.member_id = c.member 
                         AND d.customer = c.customer_id 
                         AND d.txn_date = '2013-04-30') 
       AND p.txn_date = '2013-05-08'
```

Comment: What language? Also, you should format your code.

Comment: @MichaelJCox Looks like Es-queue-el. Unless you're asking for the platform.

Comment: It would be useful to know what dialect of SQL this is; it would be even more useful to know what is meant by "it[']s not working".

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO platform. I originally meant it in terms of which variant - TSQL, PL/SQL, etc but 'platform' is more clear:).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Your second subselect lacks a join condition for member_payment p, so you were getting a cartesian join, which is undesirable.

This is another reason you should use modern join syntax, because then you can see exactly how each table is getting joined.  Also, do not re-use the p alias in both the update statement and the subselects.  For example, I have patched up the second subselect by adding the join condition p.payee = v.vendor_id from the first subselect:

```
UPDATE member_payment
SET debtor_receipt = 
    (SELECT Sum(d.amount) 
    FROM debtor_receipt d
    JOIN customer c ON c.customer_id = d.customer
    JOIN dairy_member m ON m.member_id = c.member
    JOIN vendor v ON v.member = m.member_id
    JOIN member_payment p ON p.payee = v.vendor_id
    WHERE d.txn_date = '2013-04-30') 
WHERE payee IN 
    (SELECT v.vendor_id 
    FROM debtor_receipt d 
    JOIN customer c ON c.customer_id = d.customer
    JOIN dairy_member m ON m.member_id = c.member
    JOIN vendor v ON v.member = m.member_id
    JOIN member_payment p ON p.payee = v.vendor_id
    WHERE d.txn_date = '2013-04-30') 
AND txn_date = '2013-05-08'
```

I'm not sure what this update statement is trying to do.  Perhaps you intend for the first subselect to sum up debtor_receipt.amount for each member_payment.payee who is returned by the second subselect?  We can also remove the member_payment table from the subselects, since the vendor table already contains the necessary vendor_id.  Something like:

```
UPDATE mp
SET mp.debtor_receipt = 
    (SELECT Sum(d.amount) 
    FROM debtor_receipt d
    JOIN customer c ON c.customer_id = d.customer
    JOIN dairy_member m ON m.member_id = c.member
    JOIN vendor v ON v.member = m.member_id
    WHERE d.txn_date = '2013-04-30'
    AND v.vendor_id = mp.payee) 
FROM member_payment mp
WHERE mp.payee IN 
    (SELECT v.vendor_id 
    FROM debtor_receipt d 
    JOIN customer c ON c.customer_id = d.customer
    JOIN dairy_member m ON m.member_id = c.member
    JOIN vendor v ON v.member = m.member_id
    WHERE d.txn_date = '2013-04-30') 
AND mp.txn_date = '2013-05-08'
```

You should run the subselects individually and work on them until they are returning the data you expect, and then assemble them into an update statement that does what you want.

Comment: The second form is non-standard SQL and might not work on all DBMS.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if OP told us the database.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe your code is failing because you can't get to member_payment outside of the parenthesis.

---

```
UPDATE member_payment AS p 
SET    debtor_receipt = (SELECT Sum(d.amount) 
                     FROM   debtor_receipt d, 
                            customer c, 
                            dairy_member m, 
                            member_payment p, 
                            vendor v 
                     WHERE  m.member_id = c.member 
                            AND d.customer = c.customer_id 
                            AND p.payee = v.vendor_id 
                            AND v.member = m.member_id 
                            AND d.txn_date = '2013-04-30'
                            AND p.payee IN(SELECT vendor_id 
                                              FROM   vendor v, 
                                                     debtor_receipt d, 
                                                     customer c, 
                                                     dairy_member m, 
                                                     member_payment p 
                                              WHERE  v.member = m.member_id 
                                                     AND m.member_id = c.member 
                                                     AND d.customer = c.customer_id 
                                                     AND d.txn_date = '2013-04-30')
                                   AND p.txn_date = '2013-05-08'                                

                            )
```